# Ajax File uploader

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, file-upload, swfupload

I just wanted to ask a question about uploading files via AJAX. I have researched on the web and found many articles on doing this. I am using ASP.NET 2.0.

I am probably going to go the jQuery route on this one, but I'm still unsure, I just need some feedback. Bacause my aim is to create an admin page for my client to add new products to his site when my client wishes to, so my client wants a simple file uploader and a multiple file uploader.

The first question is which is the best AJAX File Uploader to use?

The second question is how many files can you upload via AjAX, are there limits to how much you upload with different techniques ie. using jQuery or SWFUpload or using IHTTPHandler?

I would be grateful for your feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out http://www.plupload.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to do this for an item here at work.  To keep things rather simple, I went old-school and used a hidden iframe to do the file transfer in the background.  There may be more fancy ways, but this worked for me.  Also, there's no headaches when Adobe pushes out a bad update.

It was a while ago, so I can't remember the nuts n' bolts of the top of my head, but here's an article that seems to be using the same idea:

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

Answer (score 1):

This is a `subjective question`, as there is no one solution fits all for *your* application.  The right answer is the uploader that meets your business needs.  Limitations, if they exist, are set per whatever component you decide to use.